# How do I Get Support for Acer E5-573-54zv Touchpad on a Custom Kernel

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, touchpad, acer

I'm compiling a kernel just for learning purpose, and I almost get all things working, bluetooth, hdmi, usb, card reader, webcam, wifi... etc. But I can't make touchpad works, all that I know about it is...

**xinput**:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB OPTICAL MOUSE                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYN1B81:01 06CB:2970 Touchpad             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam: HD WebCam                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

**cat /proc/bus/input/devices**:

```
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=06cb Product=2970 Version=0100
N: Name="SYN1B81:01 06CB:2970 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-SYN1B81:01
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/INT3432:00/i2c-0/i2c-SYN1B81:01/0018:06CB:2970.0002/input/input11
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event7 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=6420 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=2e0800000000003
B: MSC=20
```

**dmesg | grep SYN1B81:01**:

```
[   11.112159] i2c_hid i2c-SYN1B81:01: i2c-SYN1B81:01 supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
[   11.112178] i2c_hid i2c-SYN1B81:01: Linked as a consumer to regulator.0
[   11.112181] i2c_hid i2c-SYN1B81:01: i2c-SYN1B81:01 supply vddl not found, using dummy regulator
[   11.133437] input: SYN1B81:01 06CB:2970 Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/INT3432:00/i2c-0/i2c-SYN1B81:01/0018:06CB:2970.0002/input/input7
[   11.133526] input: SYN1B81:01 06CB:2970 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/INT3432:00/i2c-0/i2c-SYN1B81:01/0018:06CB:2970.0002/input/input8
[   11.133598] hid-generic 0018:06CB:2970.0002: input,hidraw1: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [SYN1B81:01 06CB:2970] on i2c-SYN1B81:01
[   11.133664] probe of i2c-SYN1B81:01 returned 1 after 21592 usecs
[   11.224691] input: SYN1B81:01 06CB:2970 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/INT3432:00/i2c-0/i2c-SYN1B81:01/0018:06CB:2970.0002/input/input11
[   11.224837] hid-multitouch 0018:06CB:2970.0002: input,hidraw1: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [SYN1B81:01 06CB:2970] on i2c-SYN1B81:01
```

So this is basically all that I know about it, lspci -k doesn't show the touchpad, and lsmod just list two modules related **i2c_hid** and **hid_multitouch** I've tested the others disabling them and seeing if it was related if touch. And this is the latest **[config file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ltsdw/Custom-Kernel-Config/master/config-5.0-custom)** that I compiled and I don't know how to get support for this touch, I already enabled everything related with i2c, usb, hid that have elan, elantech, synaptics, designware and nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading about i2c I find out what I was missing, basically:

```
CONFIG_X86_INTEL_LPSS
PINCTRL
CONFIG_MFD_TPS68470
CONFIG_I2C_DESIGNWARE_CORE
CONFIG_I2C_DESIGNWARE_PLATFORM
CONFIG_I2C_DESIGNWARE_SLAVE
```

Comment: also multitouch and i2c_hid.